# ng-token-auth reset password not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, access-token

I've been trying for hours to get password reset to work with ng-token-auth and devise-token-auth

According to docs

```
$auth.requestPasswordReset($scope.pwdResetForm)
    .then(function(resp) {
      // handle success response
    })
    .catch(function(resp) {
      // handle error response
    });
```

ng-token-auth config

```
angular.module('lessons').config ( $authProvider, RESOURCES ) ->
  $authProvider.configure({
    apiUrl: RESOURCES.DOMAIN
    passwordResetPath:       '/auth/password'
    passwordUpdatePath:      '/auth/password'
  })
```

should send an email to the user with a link to create a one time session. I have all the email side of things working.

I'm currently getting

```
Unpermitted parameters: redirect_url, password
Completed 401 Unauthorized
```

My routes.rb

```
scope '/api' do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'Teacher', at: '/auth'
end
```

My login/logout and everything else is working perfectly but I can't seem to get this to work.

I've tried doing a manual `POST` using `$http` to `url: "/api/auth/password"`
with no luck. Same result.

Any help? Pretty please

Answer (score 0):

in application_controller.rb try adding password:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:password])
end
```